# How can I add kafka support to existing eventhub namespace?

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I've scaled up an existing eventhub from Basic to Standard tier but I can't find a way to enable Kafka support on it.

I know the way to create a new one with Kafka enabled, but this is not the case, I want to add Kafka support to the existing one because I've have a lot of services configured to send data to this eventhub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add Kafka support to the existing eventhub namespaces.

As of now, “enable Kafka” feature is available on newly created Event Hubs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Kafka is only supported on few clusters within a region. If your namespace is provisioned on a cluster without Kafka support then the CLI command will fail ([CLI command for updating event hub)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventhubs/namespace?view=azure-cli-latest#az-eventhubs-namespace-update) . So if a namespace is provisioned in a cluster without Kafka support you cannot covert it to support Kafka.